# Copying a reusable workflow from one SharePoint online site to another using csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I modelled a reusable sharepoint 2013 workflow using designer and published that as a feature in site collection in SharePoint online. Now I was to use the workflow template and dynamically change something in workflow and publish it in a list that is present in another site.

```
ClientContext newCtx = new ClientContext(newWeb);                    
newCtx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userId, passWord);

//workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService().RefreshLoad();
//ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDefinition
newDefinition = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDefinition(newCtx);
newDefinition.DisplayName = "CodeWorkflow";
// Replacing the stages in Workflow xaml
string newWokflowxoml = xoml.Replace("QC", "MR");
newDefinition.Xaml = newWokflowxoml;
newDefinition.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
var newWorkflowServiceManager = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager(newCtx, newCtx.Web);
newCtx.Load(newWorkflowServiceManager);
newCtx.ExecuteQuery();

newWorkflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService().SaveDefinition(newDefinition);
newCtx.ExecuteQuery();

newWorkflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService().PublishDefinition(newDefinition.Id);
newCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

In the `SaveDefinition().ExecuteQuery()`. I am getting the error like

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: DisplayName

Has anyone tried this before? Any help on this.

Thanks,
Vetrivelmurugan